# Set index.html file as baseUrl in Cypress

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to set baseUrl using the path of a file (index.html)?

I have an `src` folder on my root Cypress project which contains `index.html` I am testing.

In my `cypress.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'C:/cypress-project-name/src/index.html',
  },
})
```

But Cypress is giving a `Expected e2e.baseUrl to be a fully qualified URL (starting with http:// or https://).` error

Adding http:// also **doesn't work**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it via `baseUrl` due to validation, but Cypress is usually happy to "mount" HTML fragments using the `cy.visit()` command.

The path format is relative to project root, although an absolute path might also work

```js
cy.visit('src/index.html')
```

But the caveat is that you can't do it when your `src` requires a framework (React, Angular, Vue) to compile.

Only well-formed HTML that the browser can understand will work.

If you want something that's more generally applicable, handling frameworks and bundling, take a look at [bahmutov/start-server-and-test](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test)

---

#### Alternative config to baseUrl

Although `baseUrl` setting has validation constraining the format, you can use an `env` setting to bypass that validation.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  ...
  env: {
    myBaseUrl: 'src/index.html',
  },
})
```

```js
cy.visit(Cypress.env('myBaseUrl'))
```

Comment: The alternate solution worked for me. Also working using a separate `cypress.env.json` file.